# Accessibility: Visibility on Hover - How can I add screenreader and ontab functionality?

Tags: html, reactjs, accessibility, screen-readers

I am building my very first React app! I am using this to build a writer's app that I want to be accessible to everyone.

I have the basic console built. There is the writing console in the center, a writer's station on the left with nav links, and an options panel on the right with buttons for environment. Here is the basic structure:

```
function Demo() {

return (
<div className='Demo'>
  <div className="movable-writer-station">
  <aside>
    <div className="left panel" id="writer-station-nav-panel">
      <nav>
        <div className="panel-links flex-column">
          <h1>Writer's Station</h1>
            <a href="#">My Stories</a>
            <a href="#">Calendar</a>
            <a href="#">Writer's Groups</a>
            <a href="#">Friends</a>
            <a href="#">Forum</a>
            <button className="btn">Invite to Sprint</button>
        </div>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <div className="writer-console-container">
        <div className="writer-station-input">
          <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="word-count">
          342
        </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    <div className="right panel" id="writer-station-button-panel">
      <div className="text options">
        <input id="ltr1" className="c-btn t1" type="button" value="F" />
        <input id="ltr2" className="c-btn t2" type="button" value="F" />
        <input id="ltr3" className="c-btn t3" type="button" value="F" />
        <input id="ltr4" className="c-btn t4" type="button" value="F" />
        <input id="ltr5" className="c-btn t5" type="button" value="F" />
     </div> 
   </div>
  </aside>
```

Now aesthetically, I will build in functionality where the entire console shows for a few seconds so sighted users know what's there, but then it disappears to provide a distraction-free view. When they need those functions, or want to change a state (A song, font style, whatever), they can simply hover on the right panel to reveal the options again.

I use visibility: none for when the panels are not hovered on. But what about screen readers and tab readers? I've learned that this CSS property will not allow the user access to these functions at all. How can I provide the experience of allowing all of the functionality, while also providing the visual aesthetic I'm hoping for?

Note: I am using a program called "OmmWriter" as the inspiration for this, if you'd like an example of implementation. Though my app would have different and additional functionality, and will be able to use as a web app.

Comment: Typically you'll need some accessible way to toggle the console, something a user can tab to or get to through other accessible means. This also means you need to render the console in an aria live region so screen readers announce when elements they may not be focused on change state (i.e. hidden/visible).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I also just realized I can use Opacity & color: transparent instead of visibility to get the same effect I was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

I could see you have missed a lot of points for accessibility specially for screen readers.
I would like to suggest few points which you must keep in mind while developing Accessible Web applications. (Happy to discuss more if you are interested).

**Skip Link:-** Providing a Skip link will benefit a user to skip the content which is of very little relevance, repetitive or more time consuming to navigate through (like Navigation Bar).

**Key Board Accessible:–** Few people are not comfortable using Mouse due to limited visibility of visual disabilities, so key-board itself should be enough for the navigation through whole web application and all functionalities like form filling and submission, should also be executable through keyboard.

**Contrast Ratio:-** A minimum of 4:1 contrast ratio should be maintained between text and background behind the text during designing.

**Alternate text:-** Descriptive meaningful “alt”  text for media content should be provided so that the screen reader reads it for visually challenge people.
 Label for Form Elements:– Input field, check-boxes, radio buttons  and select boxes should have an associated label for better user experience.

**Non-essentiality on Color:–** Content information should never be left on colors only to pass on information to user.  Descriptive text information should also be provided for partially blind persons.

**Avoid JavaScript Link:–** link() method is not standard and should not be used as it is not supported for all the browsers.

**Focus on Active Elements:-** The active/focused links, buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, select-box dropdown and input elements should have a highlighted area around it so that user could easily understand where he is on the webpage.

**Fieldset and Legend Use:–** The fieldset tag is used to group related elements in a form and legend tag is used to give a caption to those elements. In this way form elements can be grouped together into identified categories.

**Anchor Tag href:–** “href” of Anchor tag should never be left empty. It must contact a URL and if no redirect action is required then “javascript:void();” should be used. This will make the Anchor link accessible and focus will go to the link.

**ID Conflict:-** It is in general very bad practice to use Ids and if needs to be used, it must be taken care that any page must not have an Id more than once.

**Pause Button for Moving content:–** There must be a Pause button or link to stop the moving content like Carousel or Video and Audio so that the user who reads or understand taking more time get enough to go through content.